# not able to store mouseclick coordinates in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent

I have utilised a mouse click event to display to the terminal the coordinates of the mouse click within a plot.

```
def onclick(event):
        if event.inaxes is not None:
            print(event.xdata, event.ydata)

        else:
            print("Clicked outside axes bounds but inside plot window")


    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

This code works, however if I wish to store the coordinates by doing this:

```
coords = []
    def onclick(event):
        if event.inaxes is not None:
            coords.append(event.xdata, event.ydata)

        else:
            print("Clicked outside axes bounds but inside plot window")


    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

My python crashes.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Or if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the crash is that `append` only takes 1 input.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not crash. It will instead throw an error and tell you what is wrong. In this case it would tell you something like

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

from which you can deduce that you have one argument too much.

Possible solutions: You may append a tuple,

```
coords.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
```

or you may use two lists,

```
coordx.append(event.xdata)
coordy.append(event.ydata)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Python did not throw this error and simply crashed (even when I left it for 10 minutes) hence I thought it was severe enough to ask Stackoverflow (even though the solution is fairly trivial). Thank you for your prompt reply and solutions.